# How to use it in itext Hyphenation Auto cyrillic

Tags: java, itext

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.setWidthPercentage(10);

Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.setHyphenation(new HyphenationAuto("ru", "ru", 2,2));
phrase.add(new Chunk("привет мир ",font3));

table.addCell(phrase);
document.add(table);
```

The test is not correctly displayed!!

Can I apply "ru" to Hyphenation?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new `HyphenationAuto(String lang, String country, int leftMin, int rightMin)` object as follow:

- `lang` - the language ("en" for English, for example)
- `country` - the country ("GB" for Great-Britain or "none" for no country, for example)
- `leftMin` - the minimum number of letters before the hyphen
- `rightMin` - the minimum number of letters after the hyphen

In Summary, you could use `ru` as country code for Russian.

Comment: does not work, is not correctly transferred 

           `chunk.setHyphenation(new HyphenationAuto("ru", "none", 2,2));`

Comment: Try `chunk.setHyphenation(new HyphenationAuto("ru", "RU", 2,2));`

Comment: did't help(((((

Comment: This is an answer that assumes the use of an old, no longer supported version of iText. It won't work if you don't include the hyphenation rules in your CLASSPATH. Those hyphenation rules are in a separate jar. If the code provided my M. Fuchs doesn't work, then you didn't include that separate jar. I up-voted this answer because it's the correct answer. I'd only like to suggest to add a line saying: "don't forget to add the jar with the hyphenation rules."